# Scaling up viewport

Tags: libgdx

My game is 200 x 320 pixels and I want to scale this up to fit any screen. The problem is I need to scale this up in integer multiples of these dimensions so the upscaled pixels don't look uneven.

What should I put in my constructor, `render()` and `resize()` methods to achieve this?

In the constructor I now have:

```
camera = new OrthographicCamera();
camera.setToOrtho(false,200,320);
stage = new Stage(new ScalingViewport(Scaling.fill,200,320, camera));
```

In `render()`:

```
camera.update();
game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
```

And in `resize()`:

```
int widthScale = width/200;
int heightScale = height/320;
int newScale = Math.max(widthScale, heightScale);
int multiplesWidth = newScale*200;
int multiplesHeight = newScale*320;     
stage.getViewport().update(multiplesWidth, multiplesHeight, true);
camera.setToOrtho(false, 200, 320);
```

My problem is that the content isn't centered. How and where can I center whatever is on the screen? I tried with:

```
camera.position.set(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2f, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2f, 0);
```

but the screen is blank!

Comment: No viewport is currently able to scale in integer only multiples. You would need to create your own `IntegerFitViewport extends Viewport` for this.

Comment: Doesn't `stage.getViewport().update(multiplesWidth, multiplesHeight, true);` resize the viewport to this size? I think it works alright (need to add some pixel art to make sure), but the problem is the content is not centered.

Comment: Well, if you pre-calculate the viewport size and use a StretchViewport, yes that will work. But a much more clean way would be to implement a Viewport which does exactly that itself.

Comment: Ok, but how do I center the content?

Comment: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/viewport/Viewport.java#L51

Comment: Thanks for the clue but I need help. I can't make heads or tails of Libgdx documentation let alone source code, which is why I'm begging for help all the time. Can someone please help me?

Comment: What do you actually want to center on? If it's on a player or something like that, you center it via `camera.position.set(playerPosition.x, playerPosition.y, 0)`

Comment: The player is represented by an `Image`. When I resize the window, the player's position changes visually but the coordinates (playerIcon.getX() and playerIcon.getY()) remain the same. The sprites present also change position visually but their coordinates remain the same. It's driving me nuts!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are trying to center the screen using the screen dimensions and not the world dimensions.

Try replacing

```
camera.position.set(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2f, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2f, 0);
```

with

```
camera.position.set(stage.getViewport().getWorldWidth()/2f, stage.getViewport().getWorldHeight()/2f, 0);
```

EDIT:

Okay, so here is an explanation why I proposed you set the camera to `(width/2, height/2)`. (I will leave out the third z-Coordinate from now on as it will always be 0.)

`camera.position.set()` sets the center point of the camera. At `(0,0)` the camera is positioned right at the center of the screen, depicted by the red rectangle below. What libgdx does by default, and what I proposed offsets the camera by `width/2`(the blue line) and `height/2`(the green line) which translates to the magenta rectangle.

Side note: the reason `camera.position.set(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2f, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2f, 0);` didn't work is because `Gdx.graphics.getX()` returns the width and height of the window in pixels, not in the measurement system the Viewport uses. This offsets the camera about a meter up and to the right, where you obviously didn't draw anything.

If you want the red rectangle as camera, you can change the last argument of

```
stage.getViewport().update(multiplesWidth, multiplesHeight, true);
```

to `false`. Or use `camera.position.set(0,0,0);`

[image: libgdx camera's]

Comment: It's still not centered. I tried putting this in `resize()` after `stage.getViewport.update()` and in `render()` before `camera.update()` and it has no effect. Looks exactly the same with or without this line.

Comment: How much is the screen off-center and to where?

Comment: Depends on the size of the window, but the content seems to be docked to the bottom left (if that makes sense).

Comment: The problem is setting the position of the camera like you suggested has no effect. Looks the same whether the line is there or not.

Comment: Okay, correct me if i'm wrong but `camera.position.set(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2f, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2f, 0);` made the screen go blank, and `camera.position.set(stage.getViewport().getWorldWidth()/2f, stage.getViewport().getWorldHeight()/2f, 0);` made no difference, right? if so try `camera.position.set(0, 0, 0)` to see if that is what you want.

Comment: No, sorry, I meant no difference vs deleting your line, like your line is what happens by default anyway. But there is a difference if I replace my `camera.position.set(Gdx.graphics...)` line with yours.

Comment: And what does `camera.position.set(0,0,0)` do?

Comment: Blank screen again :(

Comment: This will be the last I say about this because stackoverflow is getting angry at me for chatting too much, and I don't have enough rep yet to talk in a chat. I can't think of much any more so try and poke around a bit to solve it for yourself. See what happens if you divide by `4f` instead of `2f`, `println()` all the numbers to see if you can work anything out etc. If you have any breakthroughs post them, I'll be back tomorrow.

Comment: I updated the answer to explain why I suggested what I did, if it doesn't work I hope it helps anyway.